# Problems with installing python 3.6 libraries via pip - python36.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to install python libraries via the pip command (including but not limited to the "tensorflow" library) from the windows 10 shell. I want to use the Anaconda Python distribution, so I downloaded Anaconda3 (5.0.1 - 64 bit) and followed the official instructions from [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows][1].

Unfortunately, both ways suggested by tensorflow don't work out for me. Since only the "native pip installation" is officially supported and I am receiving the same system error by trying to install tensorflow via anaconda, I will only show you the code using pip. However, trying to install e.g. the "pyDOE" library, I get the same error message):

**using native pip**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\WINDOWS\system32> python -V
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.

C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip3 install tensorflow
Der Befehl "pip3" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.3.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached protobuf-3.5.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached tensorflow_tensorboard-0.4.0rc3-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.1 in c:\users\constantin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Collecting enum34>=1.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\constantin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\constantin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\constantin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.3.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\users\constantin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
  Using cached bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
  Using cached Markdown-2.6.10.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 3221225781 in C:\Users\CONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ldme8yek\markdown\
```

Additionally, a System Error Window appears which tells me that the execution of the code can not be continued because python36.dll can not be found. Reinstallation is said to fix the problem, but it doesn't.

python36.dll is located in this path:

```
C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3
```

Anaconda has been added to the path variables during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the reason is `pip` has no access to Anaconda python (as `pip` only uses its own packages). According to the [official instruction page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), TensorFlow can be installed using either `pip3` (which has python 3.6) or anaconda (via creating a new environment). Please strictly follow either method and see if there is any problem.

Comment: I strictly followed the instructions from both approaches seperately, but it is not working. I even downloaded python from python.org in different versions, I upgraded my pip and setuptools but I still get the same error.

Comment: From your problem description, you were using `pip`. Please try `pip3` instead of `pip`. Or, I myself prefer "Anaconda + TensorFlow + PyCharm" setup as it is much easier to install packages and I do not need to worry about package dependencies.